# Código SQL Server para pergunta

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, ssms

Após 1 hora de volta desta pergunta não consigo resolver o código para a mesma. Alguém me pode ajudar?

Pergunta: "Indique a quantidade de pilotos por cada marca de carro"

As tabelas de SQL Server criadas foram as seguintes:

```
CREATE TABLE Carro(
IdCarro INT NOT NULL,
Marca VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Modelo VARCHAR(50),
PRIMARY KEY (IdCarro));

CREATE TABLE Piloto(
IdPiloto INT NOT NULL,
Nome VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Morada VARCHAR(50),
Telefone INT,
PRIMARY KEY (IdPiloto));

CREATE TABLE Equipa(
IdEquipa INT NOT NULL,
Nome VARCHAR(20),
Morada VARCHAR(50),
Telefone INT,
PRIMARY KEY (IdEquipa));

CREATE TABLE Patrocinador(
IdPatrocinador INT NOT NULL,
Nome VARCHAR(20)NOT NULL,
Morada VARCHAR(50),
PRIMARY KEY (IdPatrocinador));

CREATE TABLE Prova(
IdProva INT NOT NULL,
Nome VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Local VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Data DATE NOT NULL,
NrVoltas INT NOT NULL,
MelhorTempo TIME,
PRIMARY KEY (IdProva));

CREATE TABLE EquipaParticipaProva(
IdEquipa INT NOT NULL,
IdCarro INT NOT NULL,
IdPiloto INT NOT NULL,
IdProva INT NOT NULL,
TempoPorVolta TIME,
TempoFinal TIME,
PosicaoRelativa INT,
PosicaoFinal INT,
FOREIGN KEY (IdProva) REFERENCES Prova(IdProva),
FOREIGN KEY (IdCarro) REFERENCES Carro(IdCarro),
FOREIGN KEY (IdPiloto) REFERENCES Piloto(IdPiloto),
PRIMARY KEY (IdEquipa,IdPiloto,IdCarro));

CREATE TABLE PatrocinadorOficial(
IdPatrocinador INT NOT NULL,
IdProva INT NOT NULL,
Valor MONEY NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (IdProva) REFERENCES Prova(IdProva),
PRIMARY KEY (IdPatrocinador, IdProva));

CREATE TABLE PatrocinadorNaoOficial(
IdPatrocinador INT NOT NULL,
IdProva INT NOT NULL,
Valor MONEY NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (IdProva) REFERENCES Prova(IdProva),
PRIMARY KEY (IdPatrocinador, IdProva));

CREATE TABLE Mecanico(
IdMecanico INT NOT NULL,
Nome VARCHAR(20),
Morada VARCHAR(50),
Telefone INT,
PRIMARY KEY (IdMecanico));

CREATE TABLE Afinacao(
IdAfinacao INT NOT NULL,
IdMecanico INT NOT NULL,
IdEquipa INT NOT NULL,
TipoAfinacao VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
TempoDespendido TIME,
Data DATE NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (IdEquipa) REFERENCES Equipa(IdEquipa),
FOREIGN KEY (IdMecanico) REFERENCES Mecanico(IdMecanico),
PRIMARY KEY (IdAfinacao));
```

Posteriormente foram inseridos nas mesmas "values" para teste.

"Inserts" colocados para teste:

```
INSERT INTO Carro
VALUES (1, 'Nissan', 'Skyline');

INSERT INTO Carro
VALUES (2, 'Subaru', 'Impreza');

INSERT INTO Carro
VALUES (3, 'Mitsubishi', 'Evolution');

INSERT INTO Piloto
VALUES (111, 'Piloto1', 'Castelo Branco', 111111111);

INSERT INTO Piloto
VALUES (112, 'Piloto2', 'Castelo Branco', 111111112);

INSERT INTO Piloto
VALUES (113, 'JaGanhou', 'Lisboa', 111111113); 

INSERT INTO Piloto
VALUES (114, 'AsdoVolante', 'Lisboa', 111111114);

INSERT INTO Equipa
VALUES (001, 'OsAtolados', 'Castelo Branco', 272722123);

INSERT INTO Equipa
VALUES (002, 'Sparco', 'Lisboa', 212312432); 

INSERT INTO Equipa
VALUES (003, 'ESTeam', 'Castelo Branco', 272343573);

INSERT INTO Prova
VALUES (010, 'RallycrossCB', 'Castelo Branco', '2017-02-02', 4, '00:04:23');

INSERT INTO EquipaParticipaProva
VALUES (002, 3, 113, 010, '00:01:20', '00:04:40', 2, 2);

INSERT INTO PATROCINADOR
VALUES(921, 'IPCB', 'Av da Talagueira');

INSERT INTO PATROCINADOR
VALUES(922, 'Bells Bar', 'Praceta Qualquer Coisa');

INSERT INTO EQUIPAPARTICIPAPROVA
VALUES(1, 3, 111, 11, '00:01:00', '00:10:00', 1, 1);



INSERT INTO Prova
VALUES (11, 'RallyLels', 'Bells', '2017-03-04', 10, '00:10:00');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É só usar um `COUNT` com `DISTINCT` agrupados pela `Marca`:

```
SELECT car.Marca,
       COUNT(DISTINCT epp.IdPiloto) AS quantidade
  FROM carro car
       INNER JOIN EquipaParticipaProva epp ON epp.IdCarro = car.IdCarro
 GROUP BY car.Marca
```

- O [`GROUP BY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms177673(v=sql.120).aspx) por `Marca` garantirá que o resultado seja agrupado pelas diferentes marcas;
- O [`DISTINCT`](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187831(v=sql.105).aspx) garantirá que cada `IdPiloto` apareça apenas uma vez por agrupamento;
- O [`COUNT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms175997.aspx) contará as linhas resultantes do produto cartesiano do `JOIN` entre a tabela `carro` e `EquipaParticipaProva`;

Comment: Olá @Sorack . Tentei o seu código. No entanto não consegui o resultado esperado pois só tinha inserido 3 carros e dos 3 carros apenas um era utilizado por 2 pilotos diferentes. Assim sendo, o resultado do código é errado pois aparece Nissan -2 , Mitsubishi -2 e Subaru-2 .

Comment: Coloquei o script de insert @Sorack

Comment: Muito Obrigado @Sorack . Já estava a dar em maluco com isto. Salvou-me!